# Problems with finding out the distance image using FCM clustering and Luv transormations

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have used **FCM clustering** to seprate the image of human skin from its background and using **Luv Tranformation** I want to find out **Burn Region** in the skin. I have found out 2 distance images for the same using formulas

```
u = (4*X)/(X+ 15*Y + 3*Z)
```

and

```
v= (9*Y)/(X+ 15*Y + 3*Z)
```

I am not able to find a correct distance image using which I can distinguish b/w the burn area and the skin. Please help me out.

Using the matlab code http://code.stypi.com/vaibhavpnd/final.m

**Input Image**
[image: Orignal Image]

**Classified Image**
[image: Classified Image]

**Segmented Image**
[image: Segmented Image]

**u co-ordinate**
[image: u co-ordinate]

**v co-ordinate**
[image: v co-ordinate]

Comment: Link to the code you provided does not work anymore. Could you attach it directly to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% accurate but most of the information is laying in the lightness (L) dimension and not so much in the u-v plane. Skin being pink is a lighter shade of the burned/red skin. There seems to be two pinks, magneta which is high chroma purple and pink which is light red (between gray and red).

I would use L and u in place of u and v in order use the fuzzy k means clustering algorithm, or simply L. Isn't the k means usable over a general number of dimensions?

Nonetheless, most of your info is in the lightness. Hope this helps.